# WPF Foreach Row Visibility Set

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, foreach, filter

I am creating an application using WPF where a Search string will filter a datagridview, but it can include multiple search strings.
I have tried to create a filter function below, but it's not quite working at the last bit where I set the visibility. Can you guys help me understand where I have gone wrong, please?
Thanks

```
private void BindGrid(string parameter)
    {
        string[] array = parameter.Split();
        string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SearchTable.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Projects", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        dataGridView1.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = dt });

                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    int index = reader.GetInt32(0);
                                    string a = reader.GetString(1);
                                    string b = reader.GetString(2);
                                    string c = reader.GetString(3);
                                    string d = reader.GetString(4);
                                    string e = reader.GetString(5);
                                    string f = reader.GetString(6);
                                    string g = reader.GetString(7);
                                    string h = reader.GetString(8);
                                    string i = reader.GetString(9);
                                    string j = reader.GetString(10);
                                    string t = a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + e + " " + f + " " + g + " " + h + " " + i + " " + j;

                                    foreach (string value in array)
                                    {
                                         if (t.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) == -1)
                                         {  
                                             row.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                                         }
                                         else if (t.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) > 0)
                                         {
                                             row.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                                         }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            reader.Close();
                        }                          
                        rows = dataGridView1.Items.Count.ToString();          
                        Rows.Content = rows + " Entries";
                    }
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: WPF does not support the `DataGridView` construct. (Also `DataGridView` has no `Items` property.) Perhaps you meant [`DataGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx)? If so, please edit your question tags so that your question can get more attention from the correct people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the visibility of the row to `Visible` only if last `value` from `array` exists in the combined string `t`. Also the row is not set to visible if `value` is at the beginning of the string (so that `IndexOf` returns `0`)

```
foreach (string value in array)
{
     // each time we are here, we are going to overwrite the row.Visibility, 
     // so only the value that was set in the last iteration stays.
     if (t.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) == -1)
     {  
         row.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
     }
     // also > 0 restricts the substring to be found in the beginning of the string
     // you've probably meant >= 0 or != -1
     else if (t.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) > 0)
     {
         row.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
     }
}
```

I think you want to set it to visible if at least one value is a substring of the combined string `t`.

```
row.Visibility = array.Any(value => t.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) != -1);
```

The second problem is that the loop is operating with the `DataTable` rows, not `DataGrid` rows. As you are updating the grid in the `BindGrid` method, you can bind the grid only to the rows you want to show.

```
private void BindGrid(string parameter)
{   
    string[] array = parameter.Split();
    string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SearchTable.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Projects", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    List<DataRow> rowsToShow = new List<DataRow>();
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                int index = reader.GetInt32(0);
                                string a = reader.GetString(1);
                                string b = reader.GetString(2);
                                string c = reader.GetString(3);
                                string d = reader.GetString(4);
                                string e = reader.GetString(5);
                                string f = reader.GetString(6);
                                string g = reader.GetString(7);
                                string h = reader.GetString(8);
                                string i = reader.GetString(9);
                                string j = reader.GetString(10);
                                string t = a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + e + " " + f + " " + g + " " + h + " " + i + " " + j;

                                if (array.Any(value => t.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) != -1))
                                {
                                    rowsToShow.Add(row);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                    dataGridView1.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = dt });
                    rows = dataGridView1.Items.Count.ToString();
                    Rows.Content = rows + " Entries";
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you filhit, however I am receiving an error on the word 'Visibility' - 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Visibility' and no extension method 'Visibility' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: @Dinoduck94 oh... Now I see this. You are iterating over the rows in the `DataTable`, not the `DataGrid` rows. You can try the updated code from my answer.

Comment: Very much appreciated for your help. I used you code above however I put the indexes of the rows required into a string array and filtered the rows using the string array via 'RowFilter'. Thanks again